# Mule 3 TLS what is the recommended keystore type

Tags: mule, tls1.2, pkcs#12

What is the recommended keystore/private key type for Mule 3.x? In Mule 3 [TLS setup documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/tls-configuration) examples use JKS. I know PKCS12 type is the default since Java 9 but Mule 3 uses Java 8. Is it fine to use PKCS12 with Mule 3.x or better stick with JKS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule doesn't makes any recommendation. It just defines JKS as the default format for keystores if you don't specify one explicitly. Other than that it just uses what your Java implementation provides. You should instead investigate the advantages and disadvantages of each format for your specific Java version and use cases.